# My working $.ajax doesn't work on angularjs $http

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, azure

I've found no way of solving this.

I have a jQuery ajax call that has always worked. I'm creating a new app with Angularjs (I'm new) and my new, Angularjs, ajax worked perfectly. When I test published to azure I found the code no longer worked. It gives an error of 0. I kid you not.
I put the code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co) and got the same result.

I have read and tried a bunch of things. I even tried using the jQuery ajax to populate the angularjs $scope.myData . By the way it populates it correctly, however Angular doesn't seem to be aware that it has new data?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance. ;-)

I don't actually need the App Key since i setup azure to accept get requests from anyone, but in trying a bunch of stuff...

```
// Angular version:

$http({ method: 'GET', url: fullUrl, headers: { 'X-ZUMO-APPLICATION': AppKEY, 'Content-Type': 'Application/json' } })
.success(function (data, status) {
    // Success
    angular.copy(data, $scope.data);

})
    .error(function (data, status) {
        // Error
        alert(status);

    });
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: startOfUrl + "recetas",
    headers: {
        "x-zumo-application": AppKEY
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
        // My work
    },
    error: function (x, status, Err) {
        alert(status);
    },
    complete: function () {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a Plunkr but didn't include the link so it's hard to debug. What you've written isn't a 1:1 replacement for your $.ajax call. A few comments:

1. Content-type isn't **supposed** to be case-sensitive, but I've seen plenty of servers that didn't fully comply with the spec. Try "application/json" instead.
2. In one spot you're passing in the appkey header in lower-case, and it's upper-case in the other. This will almost certainly cause trouble - most custom app servers I've seen are definitely case-sensitive here.
3. You don't say where you get this error. Is your .error() callback actually getting triggered, or are you getting a data block back of 0?
4. You're forming your URLs differently in each call.

It's enough that without knowing more it's impossible to guess what's wrong. If you can create a Plunkr that demonstrates the problem that would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that, put my Plunkr in order and post it